# How can I get all the transaction details depends on the start and end date?

Tags: sql, vue.js, axios

I have two textboxes the first textbox is for start date and the last one is for the end date. I want to use the date to show all the transaction depends on the user input. I'm using Axios, Vue js and PHP on my system. In my function, I have one parameter which is `$transaction_date`. How can I use the start_date and end_date to manipulate the data on my transaction table? Can somebody help me? This is my query and methods.

```
  //FUNCTION
  public function getAllStartEndDate($transaction_date) {
        $sql="SELECT tbl_transaction_details.transaction_id, 
  tbl_supplier_medicine.medicine_name, tbl_category.description, 
  tbl_unit_category.unit, tbl_transaction_details.quantity, 
  tbl_supplier_medicine.price, tbl_transaction_details.total_price FROM 
  tbl_transaction_details INNER JOIN tbl_supplier_medicine ON 
  tbl_supplier_medicine.supplier_medicine_id = 
  tbl_transaction_details.supplier_medicine_id INNER JOIN tbl_category ON 
  tbl_category.category_id = tbl_supplier_medicine.category_id INNER JOIN 
  tbl_unit_category ON tbl_unit_category.unit_category_id = 
  tbl_supplier_medicine.unit_category_id INNER JOIN tbl_transaction ON 
  tbl_transaction.transaction_id = tbl_transaction_details.transaction_id 
  WHERE tbl_transaction.transaction_date >= :transaction_date AND 
  tbl_transaction.transaction_date <= :transaction_date";

        $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->execute([
            ":transaction_date" => $transaction_date
        ]);
  }

  //API
  include '../../private/initialize.php';

  $transaction_details = new Transaction_Details();

  echo json_encode($transaction_details->getAllStartEndDate($_GET['keyword']));


  //METHODS
  searchByDate : function() {
        axios.get(this.urlRoot + this.api + 
        "search_start_end_date_transaction.php?keyword=" + 
        this.start_date)
        .then(function (response) {
            vm.reports = response.data;
            console.log(response);
        });
  }
```